# Where is the breaking change?

Tags: haskell, yesod

I wrote a CRUD application to interface with JIRA. I ended up upgrading my haskell enviornment, because cabal-dev doesn't solve everything. As a result, I've got some breakage, with this error anytime I try to use any code that interfaces with JIRA.

```
Spike: HandshakeFailed (Error_Misc "user error (unexpected type received. expecting
handshake and got: Alert [(AlertLevel_Warning,UnrecognizedName)])")
```

After a little googling, I think this either has to do with tls or http-conduit which uses tls.

I'm currently using `tls-1.1.2` and `http-conduit-1.8.7.1`
previously I was using
`tls-0.9.11` and `http-conduit >= 1.5 && < 1.7` (not sure which exactly, old install is gone.

This is where I believe the break is happening

```
manSettings :: ManagerSettings
manSettings = def { managerCheckCerts = \ _ _ _-> return CertificateUsageAccept }
```

this is what it used to look like

```
manSettings :: ManagerSettings
manSettings = def { managerCheckCerts = \ _ _ -> return CertificateUsageAccept }
```

Here's the code that uses it

```
initialRequest :: forall (m :: * -> *). URI -> IO (Request m,Manager)
initialRequest uri = do
   initReq <- parseUrl uri -- let the server tell you what the request header
                           -- should look like 
   manager <- newManager manSettings -- a Manager manages http connections
                                     -- we mod the settings to handle
                                     -- the SSL cert. See manSettings below.
   return (modReq initReq,manager)
      where modReq initReq = applyBasicAuth username password initReq
```

Let me know if I'm left something out. I'm not sure at this point what broke between then and now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a good guess about the error source, but very unlikely: managerCheckCerts simply uses the certificate package to inspect certificates for validity. The error message you're seeing seems to be coming from tls itself and indicates a failure in the data transport. It's probably a good idea to file a bug report with tls, preferably first by narrowing down the issue to a single HTTPS call that fails (or even better, using tls alone and demonstrating the same failure).

Comment: I'll go ahead and see if I can narrow it down.